# yield in recursion bst

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I've created a templated bst class and I've implemented GetEnumerator but I'm really not happy with what've done.

so first of all I felt i needed an helper function inner visit

```
   private IEnumerable<Node<T>> innerVisit(Node<T> root)
    {
        if(root== null)
         yield break;

        if (root.Left != null)
        {
            var l = innerVisit(root.Left);
            foreach (var item in l)
                yield return item;
        }


        yield return root;

        if (root.Right != null)
        {
            var r = innerVisit(root.Right);
            foreach (var item in r)
                yield return item;
        }


    }
```

I really dislike the repeating code but couldn't find a proper solution to it
, clearly repeating the loop is unclean but also I feel that burying it under a function that would jump into this one would be bad practice to say the least. any suggestion on how to do this properly?

also to complete the implementation I've written

```
     public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator()
    {

       var res = innerVisit(_root);

        foreach (var item in res)
            yield return item;

    }
```

but that too feels bad and more of a hack to make sure it will work within foreach loop and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can solve your problem without repeating the same operations like you did, but I do think you can do it in a clearer way, it is part of the requirements to return an IEumerable and If you want to do it in a recursive way you can't prevent reapiting the yield operations (but you don't have to write all of them by yourself, System.LINQ will help us with that).
We can replace the foreach and the yield return with [Enumerable.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) method, using it we can concat the left InnerVisit IEnumerable, IEnumerable that we will create for the node itself (an array with 1 item of the current node) and the right InnerVisit IEnumerable:

```
private IEnumerable<Node<T>> InnerVisit(Node<T> node)
{
    if(node == null)
    {         
        return Enumerable.Empty<Node<T>>;
    }
    return InnerVisit(node.Left).Concat(new[] { node }).Concat(InnerVisit(node.Right));
}
```

Notice that there is no need to check if Left or Right is null before you call the recursive method because it will check it later in the inner call, if it is null we will return an [`Enumerable.Empty<Node<T>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx) instead of using yield break as you did.
We can also simplify GetEnumerator by calling GetEnumerator directly on the result of the root InnerVisit, something like this:

```
public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator()
{
     return InnerVisit(_root).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: This is effectively the same code as the OP wrote, just now a one-liner. You haven't addressed the OP's concerns, just presented what is effectively a different syntax to do what they were doing in the first place.

Comment: "I really dislike the repeating code but couldn't find a proper solution to it ", this code does not repeat all the yield return and the foreach loops. He didn't ask for another algorithm he just wanted not to repeat the same foreach and yield code all over the place.

Comment: Each call to `InnerVisit` is effectively calling `yield` on each if it's elements - it's doing so the same number of times as the OP's code. And you're calling `InnerVisit` on the left and `InnerVisit` on the right - that's repeated code. This is effectively the same code as the OP. You should try to explain how your solution is different.

Comment: You are right my code will eventually do the same operations as the OP's one, but you can't achieve the OP's desired behaviour without repeating these operations, while his code doing it in a complicated way, I think this solution is clearer and therefore a better alternative.

Comment: That would be an excellent explanation to put into your answer. You're basically saying he's doing it the right way, but here's a more succinct way.

Comment: @SomeUser thank you! it's like 1000 times more elegant but do you mind to explain to me several things within the code? (really sorry for my stupid questions:X but that's just to be sure I've understood it all) we've concated the the enumerables but we're basically returning a "big" Enumerable back to GetEnumerator, the if section returns an empty enumerable(like an empty list) and thus recursively it adds all the parts properly right? second thing is on my class GetEnumerator() we call InnerVisit(_root).GetEnumerator() that means a default GetEnumerator() exist for even the basic enumerator?

Comment: As for your first question we will recursively concat all the left child IEnumerables the current node itself as an Ienumerable and the right child IEnumerables into our result, if the node is null there is no data to return, this is the stop condition of our recursion and we will return an "empty" IEnumerable. As for your second question, every IEnumerable has a GetEnumerator method, since InnerVisit return type is an IEnumerable we don't need to reinvent the wheel and we can just use it's GetEnumerator method for our purpose, though it is possible to implement your own GetEnumerator method.

Comment: info about it [here.](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250616/implementing-ienumerator-without-using-yield-return-in-c)

Comment: @SomeUser thank you and sorry if my question was trivial :X

Comment: @LiorA you're welcome. I really suggest you to read Jon Skeet's article [Iterators, iterator blocks and data pipelines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) for more info about the topic and [Iterator block implementation details: auto-generated state machines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) if you really want to deep dive into that subject.